# bind to specific IP address on host running ansible

Tags: ssh, ansible

I have a designated a server as my provisioning agent. This system has multiple IP addresses assigned. I need to use a specific IP address explicitly.

On my managed ansible boxes, they are firewalled to only accept connections from one specific IP address that is assigned to my ansible provisioning agent.

How do I force `ansible` and `ansible-playbook` to bind to a specific IP address so that IP address is used as the source of all my connections to my ansible clients?

The equivalent flag for doing this in ssh is `-b`, and for ssh is described as follows;

`-b bind_address
     Use bind_address on the local machine as the source address of the connection.  Only useful on systems with more than one address.`

Comment: I'm confused by this sentence: *"I want this system to have a stable IP address, so I have assigned a virtual "floating" ip address to the host."*. Do you mean on the ansible controller host, i.e. where ansible playbooks are executed? By "stable IP" do you mean a static IP? Also what do you mean by *"virtual floating ip address"*?

Comment: Your right, the details of my environment are not helpful to my question. I will simplify it. But since you asked, digitialocean gives you a new IP everytime you re-create an instance. You get "floating ip" addresses which you keep, and can move between instances. This is what I'm referring to, but muddies my question.
I also found my solution is ssh_args=-b x.x.x.x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to emulate the behavior of `ssh -b` then you should be able to just add the `-b bind_address` parameter to the `ssh_args` property in your ansible configuration file.  [Here is the documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#ssh-args) for this property.

Comment: Thank you. To further help, users can wanting to bind to a specific source address should set the following in their ansible.cfg file `ssh_args = -o BindAddress=X.X.X.X`